# Replying to an e-mail or letter where two people have the same name

Tags: grammar, greetings

I see varying answers over the web on this.

Hello John and John,
Hello John

My last email I went with Hello John,
It works as intended and seems like the best way to me.

Comment: What's wrong with just *Hello*? *Hello all* can also be used, although normally for three or more people. (It's also possible to say *Hello Johns*. However, that would often be used as a kind of joke, so I wouldn't recommend it in a formal setting. But in a formal setting, you might want to use their last names anyway.)

Comment: It depends on the context, how well you know the people, if it's business or personal, how formal the business culture is if it's business, if they're your age or older, where in the world you are (traditions in India differ from USA), and many other factors. You may be able to say something jokey or maybe you should use surnames, but we don't know that.

Answer (score 1):

If two people have the same name and you want to address them in a 'formal setting' **try using the part of their name which isn't the same. For this purpose you can use their last names or even full names.** *It provides are respectable, formal environment.*

*Example:*

> Hello Mr. John Smith and John Turner,
>
> Hello Mr. Smith and Mr. Turner,

**But if it's not very formal**, *then you are free to use anything ranging from:*

> Hello,  (a simple hello works too)
>
> Hello John,
>
> Hello Johns,  (sounds a bit funny but still usable)
>
> Hello John and John,
>
> Hello Mr. John and John,   etc.

Hope, it helped (PS: I used to write formal e-mails officially for my job)